# Show div only if the value is more than 1 Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would only like to show my div if the value in the variable `colorCount` is more than 1. So far My code does not hide the div based on this. I have created the code [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/RS41/ro7umxL2/26/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $('.search').each(function(index, item) {
            var colorCount = $(item).find('.item-colours-result ul li').length;
            $(item).attr('data-search-position', colorCount);

            if (colorCount < 0 ) {

                $('.numberOfColours').hide();
            } else {
                $(this).find('.numberOfColours').html('<b>' + colorCount + '&nbsp;' + 'Colours available</b>').show();

            }
        });
    });
```

So if the `<ul>` does not have a `<li>` the div should not show.

Am I doing this correct?

Comment: `if (colorCount < 0 ) {` should be `if (colorCount <= 0 ) {`.

Comment: `(!colourCount > 0)` also works.

Comment: So if I change that code in the JSFiddle, it does not work for any of that approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The colorCount shall be < 1 or <= 0
2. The hide is generalized and need to be specific to only hide the target div.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.search').each(function(index, item) {
        var colorCount = $(item).find('.item-colours-result ul li').length;
        $(item).attr('data-search-position', colorCount);

        if (colorCount < 1 ) {
            $(this).find('.numberOfColours').hide();
        } else {
            $(this).find('.numberOfColours').html('<b>' + colorCount + '&nbsp;' + 'Colours available</b>').show();

        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result-item-1" class="search" data-search-position="1" style="width: 50%;">
<div class='item-colours-result'>
<ul class=""><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul>
</div>
<div class="numberOfColours">Test</div>
</div>



<div id="result-item-2" class="search" data-search-position="2" style="width: 50%;">
<div class='item-colours-result'>
<ul class=""><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></ul>
</div>
<div class="numberOfColours">Test</div>
</div>


<div id="result-item-3" class="search" data-search-position="3" style="width: 50%;">
<div class='item-colours-result'>
<ul class=""><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li></ul>
</div>
<div class="numberOfColours">Test</div>
</div>


<div id="result-item-4" class="search" data-search-position="4" style="width: 50%;">
<div class='item-colours-result'>
<ul class=""></ul>
</div>
<div class="numberOfColours">Test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that was it.